# How to add the marker on the map after camera animation has finished

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to draw the marker showing the user's current location although I have enabled setMycurrentLocation in map while initializing it, so I am getting the the latitude and longitude of current location . Now what I am doing is showing marker at the current location . this is how I am doing it

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 8000, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        Handler handler1 = new Handler();
                                        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {

                                                addMarker(googleMap.getLocation.getLatitude(), googleMap.getLocation.getLatitude());
```

and my  addMarker function goes like this

```
private void addMarker(Double Lat, Double Long) {

        /** Make sure that the map has been initialised **/
        if (null != googleMap) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(Lat, Long))
                            .title("You")
                            .draggable(true)
            );
        }
    }
```

So this peace of code of adding marker only works if I try it using out side of onfinished function of map animation , but

some times it gives me a null as sometimes it is unable to get the location from map. 
So I tried it to put this exactly after when the camera stop animation.

> but in my case it is not working , Any idea ? or what else other way I
>   can do to add marker when the camera stop animation .?

Comment: you don't need a "postDelayed", when animation finish, you just do what you want.
Do you remove the previous markers you create?

Comment: but if i do not implement the post delayed the app crashes , it looks like the map is not returning the location instantly

Comment: @NDorigatti  i want to put multiple marker , infact  in other funtion i am getting marker ids from the web service and i want to put many multiple markers but after the camera stop animation

Comment: which crash happens if you don't delay? the app should not crash because the callback is on the main thread, i.e. the maps thread

Comment: null point exception error occurred at the line of adding marker
addMarker(googleMap.getLocation.getLatitude(), googleMap.getLocation.getLatitude());

Comment: ah-ha, thats the problem! you should break the calls and check which one is making the crash or (way better) go in debug mode, add a breakpoint to addMarker and check which object or call is null. I think googleMap.getLocation is the 'null' object, check it!

Comment: yes it is , how can I tackle it ?

Comment: I'll put it as an answer since there are links and code to provide. Let me do that

Comment: waiting , please provide me the code as a solution I read to many links but in last I posted this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from comments and code, it seems you want to have multiple markers of the user location on the map, but the code you are using for obtaining user location is not ok (I can't find googleMap.getLocation and maybe the code is not complete).
The method getMyLocation() of google maps is deprecated:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation()

> This method is deprecated.
>
> use
>   com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead.
>   FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power
>   usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the
>   MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example
>   example code, or the Location Developer Guide.

The link points to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location

Which then ports you tu use FusedLocationProvider. You have to look at that guides to obtain user location. When you have done it, you can put that code in the onFinish callback.

If you need help for fused location provider maybe you should check for already existent questions or open a new one with the appropriate tags!

Comment: so for getting location I am using GPS of device , isnt ita good idea

Comment: yes, the gps of the device is good, but google has deprecated the "old" way of obtaining location from googlemaps and instead advices to use FusedLocationAPI for the location updates. Honestly I've never used them, but from the examples and lot of discussions online it should be easy to implement.
You can alternatively use the "old" fashioned Location Listener but is more battery consuming than fusedlocationapi.